# Auto insert non existing value with findOneAndUpdate and upsert

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, upsert

My use case :

=> UPDATE : set the current date if I found a specific email (working)

=> INSERT : a specific email with date to null if the email passed in the request is not found (not working)

I thought upsert were supposed to insert if the specific email was not found, but for some reason, it's not.

JSON Structure

```
    "listener": [
        {
            "email": "email",
            "date": "2019-06-23T00:22:52.190Z"
        }
    ],
```

Route

```
exports.add_listener = function (req, res) {
    Playlist.findOneAndUpdate(
        {"platform.strauss": req.body.url},
        {$set: {"listener.$[elem].date": new Date()}},
        {
            arrayFilters: [{"elem.email": req.body.email}],
            upsert:true,
            new:true,
        }, function (err, data) {
            err ? console.error(err) : res.status(200).send(data);
        }
    )
};
```

Comment: I feel something is not right with this line ` {$set: {"listener.$[elem].date": new Date()}` what `elem`? where is it coming from and what is the value of it?

Comment: I found this from the official documentation, for use arrayfilter : 
[link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E])

`
db.array.update(
   { },
   { $set: { "myArray.$[element]": 10 } },
   { arrayFilters: [ { element: 9 } ],
     upsert: true }
)`

Comment: Great. Thanks for posting it here